# How to evaluate the following contour integral?

Tags: problem-solving, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have recently studied Cauchy's integral formula which states that if $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function and $C$ be a positively oriented simply closed curve whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$.Then for any point $z_0$ in the interior of $C$,we have $f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$.Now using this theorem I am asked to evaluate the following integral:

$\int_C \frac{\cos z}{z(z^2+8)}dz$ where $C$ is the square whose sides are $x=\pm 2$ and $y=\pm 2$.I do not know how to proceed.We cannot apply the above theorem directly because the function is not holomorphic at $z=0$ which lies in the interior of $C$.

Comment: I wonder if it helps to think of this integrand as $f(z) / (z-z_0)$, where $z_0 = 0$ and $f(z) = \cos z / (z^2+8)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? It is a souped-up generalisation of the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: No,I do not know residue theorem

Comment: That said, MPW's comment solves the problem nicely without recourse to residues (since $\cos(z)/(z^2+8)$ has no singularities and is everywhere analytic in that square)

Comment: @FShrike The answer will be $\frac{2\pi i}{9}$ I guess then.